# Hibernate 4 and Spring Data JPA not populates collection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, junit4, spring-data

I am using Hibernate 4 and Spring Data JPA, I have a ManyToOne relationship with FetchType.EAGER, Contact has many Addresses, my problem is when I run the test I cannot get the populated collection in the Contact entity, but if I retrieve the Address entity I get access to the Contact entity.

This is Contact entitty code:

```
@Entity(name = "CONTACT")
public class ContactJPA {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<AddressJPA> addresses;
//getters an setters
}
```

This is Address entity code:

```
@Entity(name = "ADDRESS")
public class AddressJPA {
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="CONTACT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONTACT_ID", nullable = false)
    private ContactJPA contact;
//getters an setters
}
```

To retrieve and save entities I am using CrudRepository from spring framework.

This is my junit:

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JPAConfigurationTest.class })
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class ContactRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    ContactRepository contactRepository;
    @Autowired
    AddressRepository addressRepository;

    AddressJPA addressJPA;
    Integer key = 1;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        addressJPA = new AddressJPA();
        addressJPA = new AddressJPA();
        addressJPA.setAddressId(new Integer(1));
        addressJPA.setCountry("Argentina");
        addressJPA.setCity("Cordoba");
        addressJPA.setStreet("San Juan");
    }

    @Test
    public void thatRetrieveContactShouldPopulateAddress(){
        ContactJPA contact = new ContactJPA();
        contact.setContactId(key);
        contact.setEmail("test@email.com");
        contact = contactRepository.save(contact);

        addressJPA.setContactJPA(contact);
        addressRepository.save(addressJPA);

        AddressJPA retrievedAddress = addressRepository.findByAddressId(1);
        System.out.println("Address " + retrievedAddress);
        ContactJPA retrievedContact = contactRepository.findByContactId(key);

        System.out.println(retrievedContact.toString());
        assertNotNull(retrievedContact);
        assertEquals(key, retrievedContact.getContactId());
        assertEquals(1, contact.getAddresses().size());//this throws null pointer exception
        Iterator<AddressJPA> it = contact.getAddresses().iterator(); 
        assertEquals(addressJPA, it.next());
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The first questions I would ask is do you really want a bidirectional relationship in this case? They are not required with JPA and can become overly complex.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fancy, but you did not set your `address` to your `contact`. In other words, you are using your relationship only *from one side (from ADDRESS side)*. Usually before you persist your contact, you should `set` address to your contact. Doing this, you have a FK column to your `Contact` which points to concrete address's PK_ID in address table. Likely that your `Contact` did not see your Address at all, because you did not make reference to it. What you need to do is `set` address object to your contact through setter method and it will be ok for now.